# python write dictionary from csv file

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I am now struggling with writing a dictionary from a csv file.

The format of csv file is like:

```
student,    Test 1, Test 2, Test 3, Final Exam
A,          9,      19,    9,       22
B,          10,     16,    9,       26
C,          11,     17,    8,       27
D,          7,      14,    9,       18
E,          8,      20,    8,       23
weight,     0.15,   0.25,  0.2,     0.4
max_points  12      20     9        30
```

Where the 2-6 rows are students' names, their test scores on each test.
And the last two rows represent weight of each test and full score of each test seperately.

Now, I want to create a dictionary from this list that looks like:

```
{'Test 1': {'weight': '0.15', 'max_points': '12'}, 
'Test 2': {'weight': '0.25', 'max_points': '20'}, 
'Test 3': {'weight': '0.2',   'max_points': '9'}, 
'Final Exam': {'weight': '0.4', 'max_points': '30'}}
```

Where the keys are the variables of the first row in the csv file except the variable students; and in each nested dictionary, keys are the names of the first column and last two rows in the csv file: weight, max_points. The corresponding values are just values in their rows respectively.

The only thing I have come up with by now is:

```
reader = csv.DictReader(open('gradebook.csv'))
for row in reader:
    key = row.pop('Student')
```

And I have no idea about how to proceed. Thank you so much for help!!!

Comment: Your file, as shown, is _not_ a CSV file. Columns in a CSV file are separated by commas.

Comment: @DYZ technically true, but now it's become common practice to call all delimited text files as CSV. not sayint it's right or wrong, just a saying it's common.

Comment: @e4c5 It has become common practice to call digits "numbers". That doesn't make them numbers, does it? It never hurts to go back to basics.

Comment: @DYZ I am sorry for the confusion. I just omitted commas, but did you get what I mean?

Comment: @dyz note that in pandas, the function to read files like the above is named read_csv

Comment: @e4c5 True. But there is also `read_table`.

Comment: I have added commas to make it more clear

Comment: @DYZ - what? There is no standard definition for CSV. Text delimited files using various delimiters such as commas, spaces, tabs or pipes have been around since the early days of computing. They have been considered dialects of a common technique for decades and its usually called "CSV" regardless of separator and quoting schemes.

Comment: Space delimiters are fine as long as they follow the rules. The problem is that you can't use spaces as the separator and as padding to make things look nice because then you can't recognize empty cells.

Comment: @tdelaney RFC 4180, for any practical purpose, _is_ a definition https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180

Comment: @tdelaney thanks for your notice. I just want to make it look nice. But I will definitely be aware of that

Comment: @DYZ that's one definition to standardize a mime type decades after csvs came into common use.

Comment: @tdelaney As far as I remember, in the past tabular files have never been called CSV unless they were comma-separated.

Comment: @DYZ - the `csv` module is a good example of the many dialects under the rubric "CSV". Many programs that read/write "CSV" have dialog boxes that let you choose separator, quoting rules, and etc... but the menu selection is "save as csv". Its not as precise as one might like, but its still better than "INI" ... who knows what crazy stuff ends up in those!

Answer (score 3):

Use Pandas, it's a one liner

```
import pandas as pd

df = pandas.read_csv('myfile.csv', delim_whitespace=True)
{ k: { 'max_points': df[k].max(), 'weight': df[k][5] } for k in df.keys()[1:] }
```

Edit.
Opps, I see taht the OP isn't actually look for max()

```
{ k: { 'max_points': df[k][6], 'weight': df[k][5] } for k in df.keys()[1:] }
```

By the way if Pandas doesn't recognize your headers properly

```
df = pd.read_csv('/tmp/df.txt',delim_whitespace=True, header=1, names=['Student','Test 1','Test 2','Test 3','Final Score'])
```

Comment: Thanks. But can i do this without using pandas?

Comment: of course you can, with the greatest difficulty :-)

Comment: This is a cool solution, I need to familiarise myself with pandas more. I tried `min()` for the weight, but the values from the csv aren't great as binary numbers :)

Comment: @JoshSmeaton  I am also still learning! your answe is a pretty good one as well. +1

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution not using pandas that should do what you want. Note though that my csv file is an *actual* csv file, so you may need to adjust the reader creation accordingly.

```
In [13]: reader = csv.DictReader(open('tests.csv'))

In [14]: record = defaultdict(dict)

In [15]: for row in reader:
    ...:    if row['Student'] == 'weight':
    ...:        for header in reader.fieldnames[1:]:
    ...:            record[header]['weight'] = row[header]
    ...:    if row['Student'] == 'max_points':
    ...:        for header in reader.fieldnames[1:]:
    ...:            record[header]['max_points'] = row[header]


In [17]: from pprint import pprint

In [18]: pprint(record)
defaultdict(<class 'dict'>,
            {'Final Exam': {'max_points': '30', 'weight': '0.4'},
             'Test 1': {'max_points': '12', 'weight': '0.15'},
             'Test 2': {'max_points': '20', 'weight': '0.25'},
             'Test 3': {'max_points': '9', 'weight': '0.2'}})
```

If you haven't seen `defaultdict` before, whatever you pass to the constructor is what is used as the value when you try to access a key that doesn't yet exist.

Comment: thanks. But can i do this without accessing those keys. Like can I do this without doing record['test 1']['weight'] = row['test 1']?

Comment: If you don't want to use pandas you wll have to accept this answer

Comment: @JoshSmeaton  Thanks. But it does not work for me. I got this result if I do not use pprint: defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {})

Comment: @JoshSmeaton When I use pprint, I still get an empty dictionary. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: I now get where the empty dict comes from. I used row.pop('Student') in previous lines. All fixed! Thanks so much!